# Can spark task access HDFS files which are not RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs, rdd

I am writing an application in which i have to download some binary files from S3 and each task has to do processing on incoming data using these binary files.

To avoid multiple S3 calls, I have downloaded the files on HDFS in my driver program.

Each task reads incoming data and tries to read binary file from HDFS and does processing. However, i am not able to do so. I am getting nullpointerexception.

Here is the line where i am getting exception in my code :

```
val fs = FileSystem.get(sqlContext.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
```

Can anyone explain me can task node access HDFS files if they are not in from of RDD.

Comment: is this line called within a function passed to an RDD transformation to be serialized and executed on the executors?

Comment: @Neha :If the files are available in HDFS, why dont you use `sc.binaryFiles` or `sc.binaryRecords` method

Comment: @Tzar Yeah...this line is called in each transformation

Comment: @Shankar, that binary file is not distributed in nature..that is the model file..i can't use sc.binaryfiles

Comment: What do you mean with "HDFS files which are not RDD" ??

Comment: Could you add the code that's using the `val fs` mentioned in the question?

Comment: I'm getting this exact same thing. You'll get a NPE if you go `val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)` but not if you go `val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())`, and I haven't the slightest idea why.